# getting childnodes from xml node

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<response list="true">
    <count>10748</count> 
    <post>
        <id>164754</id>
        <text></text> 
        <attachments list="true">
            <attachment>
                <type>photo</type> 
                <photo>
                    <pid>302989460</pid> 
                </photo>
            </attachment>
        </attachments>
```

I need to check if there is an `<attachment>` in my `<post>`.
I'm getting all posts like this :

```cs
XmlNodeList posts = XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("post");
foreach (XmlNode xnode in posts)
{
    //Here I have to check somehow
}
```

If there is no `<attachment>` node in the post, I want to get its `<text>` instead.

Comment: What do you want to get? a list of element or values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change from an `XmlDocument` to an `XElement` you can use a LINQ query to get the number of `attachment` nodes.

```
//load in the xml
XElement root = XElement.Load("pathToXMLFile"); //load from file
XElement root = XElement.Parse("someXMLString"); //load from memory

foreach (XElement post in root.Elements("post"))
{
    int numOfAttachNodes = post.Elements("attachments").Count();

    if(numOfAttachNodes == 0)
    {
        //there is no attachment node
    }
    else
    {
        //something if there is an attachment node
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try a linq query it would be like this

```
var result = XmlDoc.Element("response")
                   .Elements("post").Select(item => item.Element("attachments")).ToList();

foreach(var node in result)
{

}
```

Comment: Problem is that his existing variables use `XmlDocument` rather than `XElement`. This is why I made my suggestion for using the latter.

Answer (score -1):

To check if there are any nodes in 'posts':

```
if(posts.Count == 0)
{
    // No child nodes!
}
```

You could do this before starting the loop.

Comment: -1. This checks for the total number of child nodes, but does not distinguish `attachments` nodes from `text` nodes.